# Need a thesaurus database

Tags: dictionary, database, thesaurus

Is there an open source thesaurus available for download? It can be in any format. Preferably not from a 1915 dictionary. I need one to merge into a database application.

Answer (score 7):

There are a number of opensource thesaurus, in several languages, available here: http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Dictionaries

I used some of them to build a web service providing thesaurus service: http://thesaurus.altervista.org/

Comment: Download the OpenOffice Thesaurus file and open the 'th_en_US_new.dat' file with notepad.