# Looking for Thesaurus Data

Tags: database, thesaurus

Looking for an open-source Thesaurus dataset which contains as many English root words and synonyms as possible. Any solutions and associated links to data would be appreciated.

Comment: Folks on StackOverflow have a tendency to shut questions down as not constructive far too soon.  This is the second time in two days that I've found a question useful, and the answer useful, yet someone shut it down.

Comment: I googled for exactly this question. The answers about wordnet sent me straight where I needed to go. Doesn't make sense the question is closed.

Comment: When someone closes a question because it's on Google, it would be very useful if the search terms were provided. Sometimes it's not laziness, but not knowing the best terms to use.

Comment: This question has clear value, and needs to be reopened.

Comment: I agree, this should be re-opened, even as it stands it has more useful info than the linked question which is nearly identical and which has not been closed as non-constructive.

Comment: @Kev how can this question be improved?

Comment: @Kenshin - it's out of my hands now, I'm no longer a diamond moderator. You could bring this up on Meta.

Answer (score 34):

Thanks to Grady Ward for releasing http://icon.shef.ac.uk/Moby/ in the public domain ;)

Comment: how would you use those files?

Comment: Sheffield site captured: https://web.archive.org/web/20170930060409/http://icon.shef.ac.uk/Moby/

Answer (score 20):

https://wordnet.princeton.edu/download

Also, OpenOffice.org has a thesaurus and is open source. You should be able to use their thesaurus database at least in another open source project.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but it would be nice if you  send across the link for OpenOffice Thesaurus downloads.

Comment: Have a look here: http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/en/dictionaries But with a little help from Google you can find it yourself. Don't forget to check the license conditions if you intend to use it in a public product.

Comment: For anyone else that comes across this, you can download the OpenOffice extension (e.g any of the English dictionaries), rename the `.oxt` file to `.zip`, and look at `th_en_US_v2.dat` or similar. That file contains a list of words and their synonyms.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Thanks, @Flimm. I replaced the link, though I am not fully aware anymore what the previously linked FAQ entry was stating exactly.

Comment: "equestrian" as a synonym for "traveling"? "Panama" as a synonym for "sailor"? This dataset is completely useless.

Answer (score 11):

Check WordNet: http://wordnet.princeton.edu/

Comment: http://wordnetcode.princeton.edu/standoff-files/core-wordnet.txt is what you are looking for...

Comment: the version in http://wordnetcode.princeton.edu/standoff-files/core-wordnet.txt  is incomplete. for example it cannot match cat with feline - something that wordnet itself can do

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this forum post](http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=49797) at digitalpoint.

Take a look at previous question here [Need a thesaurus database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336418/need-a-thesaurus-database)

Note: A simple Google search reveals a lot of links.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but none of them are helping out .I am still not able to find a thesaurus database that has all the words and its synonyms :(