# How to map two dataframes on basis of synonyms? I tried using synset, but it wasn't exhaustive

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp, nltk, synonym

Example

Dataframe: A

```
 Word_A Frequency
0 Large       10
1 Happy       15
```

Dataframe: B

```
  Word_B Document                   
0 Big        1                   
1 Huge       1
2 Great      2
3 Cheerful   1
4 Merry      3
5 Joyful     2
```

Resulting Dataframe: C

(The words in Dataframe A have been mapped to their synonyms in Dataframe B)

```
  Word_A  Word_B   Frequency Document
0 Large   Big       10         1
1 Large   Huge      10         1
2 Large   Great     10         2
3 Happy   Cheerful  15         1
4 Happy   Merry     15         3
5 Happy   Joyful    15         2
```

Comment: Love the formatting of your code...

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618304/looking-for-thesaurus-data