# Azure Search Synonym Map open source list

Tags: synonym

I am looking for an open source (free to use and modify) synonym list (like a thesaurus) where I can see the all words which have same meaning to a word?
(Please do tell me if I am unable to explain properly)

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking. Please edit your question and include more details.

Comment: Thanks for informing. Done

Comment: Azure Search does not provide this. You may find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618304/looking-for-thesaurus-data

Answer (score 0):

Rudin mentioned a stacoverflow discussion which I find useful:
 stackoverflow.com/questions/5618304/looking-for-thesaurus-data